# Code that runs on any page Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

where can i put a code snippet, which i want to be run before any other code on any page of my Zend framework application.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I mainly use ZF1, but I think that all versions of the framework have the idea of Controller Plugins (or just plugins), which can run at a number of places in the loading process. I use them to do things like check if the user is logged in, what their access control list is etc. Googling Zend Framework plugins should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> want to be run before any other code on any page

put in index.php

OR 
in Module.php add method:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
  //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Can i reach other modules from the index.php? like the Doctrine module?